# Failing a Jenkins Pipeline depending on result of sql query

Tags: sql, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline which run's sql query's and produces the results in the console output. I would like to insert a stage which can either fail or succeed the pipeline dependent on the result. The query in question produces either 'Pass' or 'Fail', I would like to have the pipeline succeed as normal if the result of the query is 'Pass', but then fail the pipeline if the result of the query is 'Fail'. Can this be done as if so how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can't return a proper error code from whatever program executing the SQL queries you can read the Jenkins console output and fail the job. Check the following code snippet.

```
def consoleLog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)).logFile.text
if(consoleLog.contains("FAILURE TEXT")) {
  error "SQL Failed, hence failing the job."
}
```